# I need json string without double quotes in keys in ios

Tags: ios, json

I upload the json string to the server like

```
 NSDictionary *values = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"name", @"objective", nil];
 NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:values,nil];
 NSDictionary *result = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:array, @"objectives", nil];
```

*I use the following code to convert the dictionary to JSON:*

```
id obj = result;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:obj options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**I get correct json like**

```
{ "objectives":[
     {"objective":"name"}
]
}
```

This is correct json but **I need json string like**

```
 { objectives:[
     {"objective":"name"}]
}
```

**Is it possible to create without double quotes in key in iOS**?

Only this json string we get the response otherwise I get error.

Comment: That's not JSON.  No JSON serializer will produce it and few JSON parsers would accept it.  If you need it, create the inner JSON string and the "wrap" it with the characters you want.

Answer (score 2):

if it is only the first key that you want to remove quotes from, you can use the following quick workaround

```
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"objectives\"" withString:@"objectives"]];
```

Comment: This is what i was gonna say. It's not really dynalic but if it works for you, thats an easy fix