# Create JSON format using NSString as a key and values

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutabledictionary

I have `JSON` format requirement something like this.

```
{ 
"first_name" : "XYZ", 
"last_name" : "ABC" 
}
```

I have values in `NSString`.

```
NSString strFName = @"XYZ"; 
NSString strLName = @"ABC";
NSString strKeyFN = @"first_name";
NSString strKeyLN = @"last_name";
```

And I use `NSMutableDictionary`

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setObject:strFName forKey:strKeyFN];
[dict setObject:strLName forKey:strKeyLN];
```

then output is

```
{
first_name = XYZ,
last_name = ABC
}
```

So I don't want "=" separating key & values instead I want ":" to separate key and values

I have went most of the [stack overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057281/creating-json-format-in-objective-c) but didn't help getting "=" only in output

So please any help ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299965/converting-an-array-into-json-array-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer :

```
NSString *strFName = @"XYZ";
NSString *strLName = @"ABC";
NSInteger number = 15;

NSString *strKeyFN = @"first_name";
NSString *strKeyLN = @"last_name";
NSString *numValue = @"Number";

NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dic setObject:strFName forKey:strKeyFN];
[dic setObject:strLName forKey:strKeyLN];
[dic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:number] forKey:numValue];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dic] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"JSON  %@",jsonString);
```

[image: See image]

Comment: @ivaran thank you but If I want to skip number from double quotes means what I have to do ?

Comment: Yes that is really useful ! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**You write this code after your NSDictionary**

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *jsonstr = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Yes that is really helpfull but it is adding double quotes to number too,
so I don't want double quotes for it, than what I have to do ?

something like this
{
"Number" : 7
}

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
NSString *cleanedString1 =[strFName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/"" withString:@""];
NSString *cleanedString2 =[strLName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/"" withString:@""];

NSDictionary *Dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                cleanedString1, strKeyFN,
                                cleanedString2, strKeyLN,nil];

NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:Dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString);
```

Comment: Yes that is really helpfull thank you, but it is adding double quotes to number too, so I don't want double quotes for it, than what I have to do ? something like this 
{ "Number" : 7 }

Comment: if you are not getting see this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817932/i-need-json-string-without-double-quotes-in-keys-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *strFName = @"XYZ";
NSString *strLName = @"ABC";
NSString *strKeyFN = @"first_name";
NSString *strKeyLN = @"last_name";
NSDictionary *ictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      strKeyFN, strFName,strKeyLN, strLName,nil];

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"dictionary as string:%@", jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert  `NSMutableDictionary` into `NSData`

then convert the `NSData` Into `json` string you want

```
NSString *strFName = @"XYZ";
 NSString *strLName = @"ABC";
 NSString *strKeyFN = @"first_name";
 NSString *strKeyLN = @"last_name";
 NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [dict setObject:strFName forKey:strKeyFN];
 [dict setObject:strLName forKey:strKeyLN];

NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict    options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

NSString *jasonString= [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Yes that is really helpfull but lets say I have number and I don't want double quotes for it, than what I can do ?

Comment: in NSDictionary key is always String But its value can be number or string . if you use value as number you not get double quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *strFName = @"ABC";
NSString *strLName = @"XYZ";

NSString *strKeyFN = @"last_name";
NSString *strKeyLN = @"first_name";

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dict setObject:strFName forKey:strKeyFN];
[dict setObject:strLName forKey:strKeyLN];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dict] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonStrng = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Your required JSON is %@",jsonStrng);
```

Answer (score 0):

this very robust code to achieve you goal

```
 NSDictionary *userDic = @{strKeyFN:strFName,strKeyLN:strLName};
```